# Node MySQL- Promise Never Ends

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I'm having an issue with promises in node, specifically in the following code, which I wrote to execute a MySQL query so all my other 100+ functions can share this instead of writing it inline. Coming from PHP development, it's been a learning curve to understand the benefits of promises and whatnot, and now I have hit a bit of a problem. Here is the function that takes `query` as a parameter, executes it, and returns the response:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const myDBConnection = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: "username",
    password: "password",
    database: "dbName",
    connectionLimit: 101,
});


class DBQueryRunner {
    query(query) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            myDBConnection.getConnection((err, connection) => {


                const myQuery = mysql.format(query.string, query.params);
                connection.query(myQuery, function(err, data) {
                    return (err ? reject(err) : resolve(data));
                    connection.release();
                });

            });

        });


    }
}
```

The code runs fine and the value gets returned to the caller, but it just doesn't seem to terminate, regardless of what I try and I'm concerned it's eating CPU resource.

Here is an example function you can run to use with the function above in command line, to see what is happening.

```
function test() {
let DBQueryRunner = require("./theAboveCode.js");
const myDB = new DBQueryRunner();

let query = {
    string: `SELECT 1+1 AS Output`,
    params: []
};


return myDB.query(query).then(rows => {
console.log(rows)
    return (rows);
});

}
```

**Questions:**
- is it necessary for the promise to terminate?
- Is there a mistake in my code?
- Is there a better way to make a reusable database execution function like I have?

**UPDATE** - I have also tried an alternative method using Bluebird to "promisify" the mysql library. The function still never ends and I have to CTRL+C in my terminal to quit it.

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);


let myDBConnection = mysql.createPool({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  myDBConnection: "dbName",
  connectionLimit: 101,
});




class DBQueryRunner {
  query(query) {
    let pool = Promise.promisifyAll(mysql);

        return myDBConnection.getConnectionAsync()
            .then(function (conn) {
                 myDBConnection = Promise.promisifyAll(conn);
                 return myDBConnection.queryAsync(query.string, query.params);
            })
            .then(function (results) {
                 if (results.length < 1) {
                     return "No results were found";
                 } else {
                     return results;
                    //  resolve(results);  //This method doesn't work with resolve/reject so I already am confused by it.
                 }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                 console.log(err);
                 throw err;
            })
            .finally(function () {
                 if (myDBConnection) {
                     myDBConnection.release();
                     console.log("Released the connection")
                 }
            });
    }

}
```

Comment: according to your code, you will never reach the instruction `connection.release();` as you have a return statement before; Maybe you should release the connection before returning the value

Comment: @oliv37 hello, I have tried that already and it made no difference. I've just got a hundred code versions trying different things. It was originally before the return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution that fixes my issue.

Using `connection.destroy()` allows the functions to properly end, so they no longer cause the "hanging".

The two sets of code I posted in my original post do work, so it might help someone else in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should call resolve('some data to return'); when all operations and you release the mysql descriptor. Try to change it to

```
connection.release(); 
return (err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)); // The return operator will EXIT from function before connection released. Maybe this is what causes the problem
```

> is it necessary for the promise to terminate?

Promise is not terminating. Promise has three states: Running, Rejected, Resolved. So .then() chain won't be called if your previous promise is still executing. So yes, you MUST set appropriate state for your promise: resolved or rejected in order to call next chained operations.

> Is there a mistake in my code?

Yes you definetely mistaken in usage of return statement. Be aware that as soon as you called **return**, your function is terminated and code after **return** statement won't be executed

Comment: Hello, so even if I removed the `return (err ? reject(err) : resolve(data));` line and replaced it with just `resolve(data);` the promise still never finishes.

I have also tried not returning the promise, but I must otherwise the caller is never going to receive anything.

Surely if the return statement terminates the function, that would not cause it to "hang" my command line?

Comment: **Update** - I have tried an alternative using Bluebird and it still causes the function to infinitely run in my terminal until I manually close it. See the update in my original post.

Comment: Check examples here https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql looks pretty nice. And pay attention that connection.release() called immediately in callback (not at the end of all processes done in callback). But I believe as you use pool of connections it is not necessary to release connection. And as you are using pool you should call pool.end(() => { resolve(data) }) to close all connections to pool when pool operations ended. So the idea is to return promise when ALL connections to pool are closed